# Specify XML tag names without using XML Attributes

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I would like to serialize an object using one of the `System.Xml.Serializer.Serialize([stuff])` methods.  Here's how the serialized output looks now:

```
<MyFirstProperty>stuff</MyFirstProperty>
<myArrayProperty>
    <typeStuff>value0</typeStuff>
    <typeStuff>value2</typeStuff>
    <typeStuff>value3</typeStuff>
</myArrayProperty>
```

Here's what I want it to look like:

```
<COLUMN>
    <COLUMN_NAME>MyFirstProperty</COLUMN_NAME>
    <COLUMN_VALUE>stuff</COLUMN_VALUE>
</COLUMN>
<COLUMN>
    <COLUMN_NAME>myArrayProperty</COLUMN_NAME>
    <COLUMN_VALUE>
        <VALUE>value0</VALUE>
        <VALUE>value2</VALUE>
        <VALUE>value3</VALUE>
    </COLUMN_VALUE>
</COLUMN>
```

Not too tough, no?  Just add XML attributes to the properties (and a couple other manipulations), as indicated by [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx), right?  Well, last I checked, the class has somewhere around a thousand properties.  I'm too lazy to fix all those!

Any suggestions, apart from breaking up the monster class into smaller ones?

Comment: `Well, last I checked, the class has somewhere around a thousand properties.` - a class with that many properties is a clear indication of a poorly designed data model.

Comment: @HighCore Yeah, people kept tacking onto it over the years.  After I plug the other leaks, one of my next projects is to fix that mess.